# Google calender API with Java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

After I have logged in and received the access token, I already have an access token, how can I call the Google calendar API? Everyone, I tried this method but it shows error 401 Unauthorized

Here is my code:
**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

private static final String GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3";

    @GetMapping("/getCalender")
    public void getGoogleCalendarEvents() throws IOException {
        String access_token = WebSecurityConfig.ACCESS_TOKEN;
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_URL + "/calendars/primary/events"))
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)
                    .GET()
                    .build();

            HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

            if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
                String responseBody = response.body();
                System.out.println("Google Calendar API response: " + responseBody);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Failed to call Google Calendar API. Status code: " + response.statusCode());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }}
```

Comment: Were is the access token comming from